# Embedded slides in webapp which can be edited on the UI

Tags: slideshow, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a webapp. I am trying to develop a feature where user should be able to edit a slide based on his import or data within my webapp/embededd slide.

Note : User is already authticated. I dont want the user to re-login again. These are enterprise users.

Please let me know if this is achievable.

Thanks

I tried embedding which works fine.

Running into problems of User signup. As I mentioned earlier, they are aleready authenticated. How to take care of this?

I am able to programatically create a slide, create some basic text, boxes. But how do I allow user to edit it online in UI?